# How can I display a number in QML with its sign, even if it is +?

Tags: qt, qml

//I know this code does the job for positive numbers but not for all numbers.

**text: qsTr ("+") + (some_positive_number)**

//Is there a way that I can always display any number with its sign beside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine in standard javascript:

```
(a - b > 0 ? "+" : "") + (a - b)
```

Note that:

1. There is little to no sense in using `qsTr` for `+` since its meaning is fairly localised and internationalised by default.
2. No need to calculate the difference of `a - b` thrice.

Answer (score 0):

text: (a - b > 0) ? (qsTr("+") + (a - b)) : (a - b)

//This will work fine.